# Compiling kernel from source got a fatal error: too few arguments to function 'part_round_stats'

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, bcache

I'm trying to compile the kernel from source on the system CentOS 7.

The output of `uname -a` is:

`Linux dbn03 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 4 20:48:51 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Here is how I download the source code and compile it:

```
wget "http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/os/Source/SPackages/kernel-3.10.0-957.el7.src.rpm"  
rpm2cpio ./kernel-3.10.0-957.el7.src.rpm | cpio -idmv
make menuconfig
     Device Drivers 
         ->Multiple devices driver support (RAID and LVM)
             -><*> Block device as cache
make bzImage
make modules
```

As you see, I just tried to compile the kernel with the module BCACHE.
However, when I executed the commands above, I got the error as below:

```
drivers/md/bcache/request.c:675:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘part_round_stats’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   part_round_stats(cpu, &s->d->disk->part0);
   ^
In file included from include/linux/blkdev.h:9:0,
                 from include/linux/blktrace_api.h:4,
                 from drivers/md/bcache/bcache.h:181,
                 from drivers/md/bcache/request.c:9:
include/linux/genhd.h:408:13: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct hd_struct *’
 extern void part_round_stats(struct request_queue *q, int cpu, struct hd_struct *part);
             ^
drivers/md/bcache/request.c:675:3: error: too few arguments to function ‘part_round_stats’
   part_round_stats(cpu, &s->d->disk->part0);
   ^
In file included from include/linux/blkdev.h:9:0,
                 from include/linux/blktrace_api.h:4,
                 from drivers/md/bcache/bcache.h:181,
                 from drivers/md/bcache/request.c:9:
include/linux/genhd.h:408:13: note: declared here
 extern void part_round_stats(struct request_queue *q, int cpu, struct hd_struct *part);
```

It seems that I got a warning and an error.

I think I can ignore the warning but the error is fatal. In the header, the function `part_round_stats` is declared that three parameters are necessary, whereas in the file `drivers/md/bcache/request.c`, only two parameters are passed to the function `part_round_stats`.

I've tried to google this issue but I got nothing.

So what kind of problem did I get here? Is this the error coming from the source code of linux? (I don't think so...), or is this some kind of issue of the versions? or the downloaded source code doesn't support the module BCACHE and the developer of kernel left a fatal error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```bsh
rpm -ivh kernel-3.10.0-957.el7.src.rpm
cd ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES
rpmbuild -bp kernel.spec
cd ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-3.10.0-957.el7/linux-3.10.0-957.fc32.x86_64
make menuconfig
make bzImage
make modules
```

Comment: `rpmbuild -rp kernel-3.10.0-957.el7.src.rpm` gave me the error: `rpmbuild: arguments to --root (-r) must begin with a /`.

Comment: I also tried `rpmbuild --rebuild kernel-3.10.0-957.el7.src.rpm`, but after executing this command, the directory `~/rpmbuild/BUILD/` is empty.

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it compatible with CentOS 7. The `-rp` option is available only in new Fedora releases.

Comment: Great! It works. Thanks a lot dude. So why did your commands work? Have your commands patched the source code or what?

Comment: This command patches the kernel source with all the RHEL/CentOS patches and also prepares the right .config file for you - the net result is that you can compile the kernel and modules the way RHEL/CentOS compile them.